# What kind of figurative language is “Clifton loomed like hulking animals.”

Tags: phrases, figurative

Clifton loomed like hulking animals.

Comment: Imagine that you are camping in the wilderness and are squatting near your campfire.  A grizzly bear approaches and stands over you.

Comment: Some would say it's not metaphor.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Of course not!  It's like a simile!

Comment: ... As metaphorical as a simile?